# How to sort single linked list under two determinants?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Ok, so i got list of some products, which have two atribiutes x and y. I need to sort them ascending by x and if there will be two products with same x then i have to sort products with same x descending by y. Note that elements are already on the list and i need to do sorting repetedly.

For now i have something like this:

```
void Sort_my_list(Product * &list, int x)  
{
  Product* sorted = 0; 
  while (list != 0) 
  {
    Product* max = list, * before_max = 0; 
    for (Product* p = list, *i = list->next_;                               
      i != 0; 
      p = i, i = i->next_) 
    {
      if (i->get_x(x) > max->get_x(x))
      {
        max = i; 
        before_max = p; 
      }
    }
    if (before_max != 0) 
      before_max->next_ = max->next_; 
    else 
      list = max->next_; 
    max->next_ = sorted; 
    sorted = max; 
  }
  list = sorted; 
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) together with [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)? All you'd need to implement would be the custom comparison.

Comment: Even if you had `std::list`, it still has a `std::list::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Decouple the *list sorting* code, from the *node comparing* code. The former can call the latter, but not be concerned with its internals.

The comparison problem is much easier: given two products, `a` and `b`, should `a` come prior to `b` in the list?

Once the comparison function is working, the sorting function can call it, and use whichever sorting algorithm you like (e.g. bubble-sort, merge-sort, insertion-sort...).

Comment: So you mean to use something like a.compare(b) , and then use list.sort()?

Comment: @JakubSiejak: Yes, that is one way. Or you could write your own `sort` that uses `compare`.